# Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061) while creating DB using rake command

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

i get this error when i try to create a database using rake command.

this is my database.yml file

```
   # MySQL.  Versions 4.1 and 5.0 are recommended.
   # 
   # Install the MYSQL driver
   #   gem install mysql2
   # Ensure the MySQL gem is defined in your Gemfile
   #   gem 'mysql2'
   #
   # And be sure to use new-style password hashing:
   #   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/old-client.html
development:
adapter: mysql2
encoding: utf8
reconnect: false
database: SIMS_development
pool: 5
username: root
password:
host: localhost
port: 3306


# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
 adapter: mysql2
 encoding: utf8
 reconnect: false
 database: SIMS_test
 pool: 5
 username: root
 password:
 host: localhost
 port: 3306
```

now i am not sure why i am getting this error.

Comment: The use of `port: 3306` implies that you are connecting to the database via TCP.  Are you sure MySQL is listening for tcp connections on the local adapter?  You may need a socket connection instead like `socket: /tmp/mysql.sock`

Comment: well i added it here coz i thought mysql will always listen at 3306 no other things in mind while using it

Comment: What platform are you running this on? Check the `my.cnf` configuration file for something like `socket = /tmp/mysql.sock` and add the socket location as `socket: /the/socket.sock` instead of the port in database.yml

Comment: i cant find configuration file are u sure it is of .cnf format?

Comment: Them I'm sorry I can't help much further. It's been years since I dealt with MySQL on a windows machine.

Comment: See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/option-files.html Might be my.ini on Win.

Comment: Can you connect to the DB otherwise, e.g. using PHPMYADMIN or another MySQL client? Are you sure the DB is running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have old mysql server. So please install new one if you have old version.

Comment: well let me see if i have any versioning issue.

Comment: guess your answer was correct tho i didnt checked it i was using mysql 5.1.4 and my installer was trying to configure 5.5.1 thx man

Answer (score 1):

Substitute `host: localhost` with `host: 127.0.0.1`

Answer (score 1):

you can use socket connection instead of a port for your connection, you can use of this form, it's very easy

for Linux:

```
development:
adapter: mysql2
encoding: utf8
reconnect: false
database: your_database_name
pool: 5
username: your_username_db
password: your_password_db
socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

for MAC

```
development:
adapter: mysql2
encoding: utf8
reconnect: false
database: your_database_name
pool: 5
username: your_username_db
password: your_password_db
socket: /tmp/mysql.sock
```

I hope this method will serve